# On Ubuntu 12.10, Empathy as startup application caused HUD to open behind other windows

Tags: 12.10, empathy, hud, startup-applications

Anyone know of a fix for this behavior.

Having Empathy as a startup application causes the HUD to only open behind other windows. It doesn't matter if the windows were opened at startup, or later, the HUD will only open behind them if Empathy is a startup application. My other startup applications don't cause this (Dropbox, Skype, Thunderbird, Ubuntu One), only empathy. Any ideas or solutions?